# Como é que vocês digitam acentos no teclado?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Minha primeira língua é o Inglês, portanto normamente eu não uso acentos em nada. A única maneira que eu tenho de digitá-los [em Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_.28Linux_and_other_Unix_variants.29) é pressionar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> e digitar um código, como `ea` para 'ê', e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Esta maneira não é especialmente difícil, porém é trabalhosa. Eu estou interessado em saber como é feito nos países de língua Portuguesa. Precisa de um teclado especial, ou é possível com programas especiais? Existe uma maneira melhor que eu poderia usar?

Comment: @earthliŋ off-topic? Uma pergunta sobre localização de idioma? Para não falar que a ajuda diz  "Questions about the following topics are allowed here: [...] Problems encountered by people learning Portuguese". Parece no mínimo dos mínimos duvidoso para um fecho de 2 votos.

Comment: @Artefacto I think that it's more about tech support than about the language. On Japanese.SE it would be blatantly off-topic, so I thought it would be off-topic here as well, but we probably should discuss this on meta. Depending on your system you can ask about keyboards/shortcuts etc. on http://superuser.com, http://apple.stackexchange.com, http://unix.stackexchange.com and, depending on the nature of the question, maybe even on http://pt.stackoverflow.com. Should I reopen this until we have a consensus?

Comment: @Artefacto I opened a discussion on meta: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/243/what-should-we-do-with-questions-related-to-computing

Comment: Embora o Inglês não exija ele permite o uso de diacríticos (acentos) em palavras que vieram do estrangeiro, a destacar Alemão e Francês, já vi algumas com o trema, cedilha e acento agudo. Exemplo que me veio agora é a palavra "façade" em inglês, escrita exatamente como é em Francês (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fa%C3%A7ade). Mas o inglês não exige o cedilha, podendo também ser escrita como "facade".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O melhor é configurar sistema operativo para usar o *layout* *US International*, o qual manterá todos os carateres na mesma posição a que estás habituado. Na versão com teclas mortas (*dead keys*) desse *layout*, introduzir <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> e <kbd>`</kbd> (<kbd>^</kbd> e <kbd>~</kbd> precisam de <kbd>Shift</kbd>) não gera por si só nenhum resultado; é preciso pressionar uma outra tecla e aí o resultado é a combinação da segunda tecla com o diacrítico correspondente (<kbd>'</kbd> corresponde ao acento agudo). Por exemplo, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> gera `á`.

O problema deste *layout* (*US-international* com teclas mortas) é que, para introduzir `^`, `` ` ``, `~` (sozinhos, sem se combinarem) e `'` e `"`, passa a ser necessário pressionar <kbd>Espaço</kbd> a seguir à tecla correspondente, já que as correspondentes teclas se terão tornado teclas mortas. Por exemplo, a tecla da aspa `"` (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>) torna-se uma tecla morta para introduzir um trema `¨` (que nem sequer é usado em português depois do acordo ortográfico); quando combinada com um espaço é produzida uma aspa (`"`) e quando combinada com um certo conjunto de letras é produzida essa letra com trema (*ä*, *ü*, *ÿ*, etc.). Isto é extremamente irritante em contextos em que tenhas de usar aspas frequentemente, como a escrever código (ainda mais irritante que o *layout* português...).
Se sentires o mesmo problema, há uma solução. Pelo menos em Linux, existe uma versão do *layout* sem teclas mortas. Para as teclas se comportarem como teclas mortas tens de combiná-las com <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. Para introduzires `á`, tens então de pressionar <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>. A versão mais adequada para ti dependerá da frequência com que tens de introduzir `"`, `'`, `~`, `^`, etc. quando comparada com aquela com que usas esses caracteres como diacríticos.

O caractere `ç` é introduzido, em qualquer das variantes, com <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.

Posto isto, restam ainda alguns caracteres usados em português não cobertos por este *layout*. As aspas francesas `«` e `»` e os `o` e `a` em *superscript*, usados em 1.ª e 1.º. Para estes caracteres, podes em Linux usar a [tecla de composição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) ou em Windows as [combinações numéricas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows). Por exemplo, em Linux `«` pode ser escrito com <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>,  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. Para `ª`, <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (*underscore*). Para mim, as combinações da tecla de composição são mais fáceis de memorizar do que códigos numéricos associados ao *code point* do caractere.

Em Portugal, o mais comum é as pessoas usarem [o *layout* português.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout) A maioria dos teclados vendidos em Portugal têm este layout impresso nas teclas, embora também se encontrem teclados com o *layout* *US* (por comparação, na Holanda, onde vivo neste momento, o *layout* holandês nunca é usado, apenas o *US*). O problema do *layout* português é que, embora seja bom para introduzir texto em português, é pouco prático para introduzir código. Por exemplo, para introduzir a chaveta `{` (um dos caracteres mais utilizados em linguagens de programção com sintaxe inspirada em *C*) ou os parênteses retos `[`, é preciso fazer alguma ginástica com a mão direita, usando o <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. Por outro lado, há uma tecla dedicada (!) para introduzir `«`/`»`.

Comment: @ANeves Exato. Para introduzires uma aspa `"`, tens de pressionar `Shift` + `'`, `Espaço`. Para introduzir `ä`, pressionas `Shift` + `'`, `a`.

Comment: Artefacto, o y pode ser uma vogal: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel

Comment: Não gosto da mistura que fazes entre 1) as teclas mortas precisarem de tecla+espaço para escrever o símbolo sozinho, e 2) a aspa se tornar uma trema, e com espaço escrever aspas. Acho que são duas coisas absolutamente distintas, e que misturá-las deixa a resposta menos clara. Adicionalmente, repara que 2.2) com esse layout de teclado fica impossível escrever `¨`. Eles fizeram uma péssima escolha ao misturar a aspa com a trema.

Comment: @ANeves Bom, não fui em que decidi que as aspas seriam um trema e as plicas uma cento agudo, por isso não vejo como evitar a "mistura". Embora verdade seja dita, não há no teclado US tecla para `´` e para `¨`, por isso não vejo como poderia ser doutra maneira. O trema ¨ pode ser introduzido com Shift + ', Shift + ' em Linux. Em Windows, se a memória me não engana, dobrar as teclas mortas produz o mesmo valor que a combinação com espaço, por isso não sei se há maneira.

Comment: Ui, não tinha percebido que as plicas são usadas para agudos... que grave, pensei que era só o caso das aspas.

Comment: Em Windows, é possível ter mais de um layout de teclado e um atalho para trocar o layout ativo é a pressionar Alt, manter pressionado, e pressionar Shift. Ambas as do lado esquerdo do teclado.

Comment: +1 para a tecla de composição em Linux. Acho essential para o meu uso bilingual do computador. Para mim, como programador, é mais conveniente/confortável do que teclas mortas. E traz outros benefícios tipográficos para além dos que já mencionou (– — × ° € ≠ ← → © ™ …). Infelizmente, na minha experiência as combinações para ª e º dependem no programa que as recebe—muitas vezes se confundem com ā e ō.

Comment: @DanGetz `ā` escreve-se combinando `a` com `-`, `ª` escreve-se combinando `a` com `_`. Nalguns tipos de letra, `ª` e `º` aparecem sublinhados.

Comment: @Artefacto seria fixe se era assim, mas no meu caso não. Por exemplo no meu browser `_`+`a` da `ā`, e `a`+`_` da `ª`. E no meu terminal, ambos dão `ā`. Um dia vou tentar alterar algumas destas configurações.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sei que tipo de teclado usas, nós em Portugal usamos este:

[image]

Este teclado e idioma português nas definições do teclado do sistema operativo.

Então só tens de clicar no botão do acento e de seguida a letra desejada, no teu exemplo seria:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> e depois <kbd>e</kbd>, isto porque o `^` é o segundo caractere da tecla do `~` e `^` e precisa do <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
No caso de `~` basta <kbd>~</kbd> e depois <kbd>a</kbd> para obter `ã`.

Se por exemplo quiseres escrever `é` (ver figura) podes fazer simplesmente <kbd>'</kbd> e depois <kbd>e</kbd>.
E <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> e depois <kbd>a</kbd> para obter `à`

[image]

Só para terminar, **tu podes usar esse tipo de configuração escolhendo apenas o idioma do teclado para português, sem teres de trocar de teclado.**

Comment: Acho que para ele isto seria bem mais confuso do que usar o _US International_, o qual mantém a maioria das teclas como estão e apenas faz com que um par delas passem a ser mortas.

Comment: @Artefacto eu em casa uso um teclado francês com configuração de idioma português e, estando habituado é natural, acabo por nem olhar para as teclas. Mas pronto fica mais uma opção ;)

Comment: O problema não é tanto o que está impresso no teclado (em Portugal uso _layout_ _US_ em teclados portugueses sem problema), mas a "memória muscular" da coisa.

Comment: @Artefacto como assim?

Comment: Quero dizer que se estás habituado a teres as teclas em determinada posição, é um processo doloroso alterar essas posições, [independentemente de olhares para o teclado ou não](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mem%C3%B3ria_muscular#Portuguese). O _layout_ _US International_ não altera a posição de nenhuma tecla, apenas requer pressionar o espaço umas vezes extra.

Comment: Sim, nisso tens razão. De qualquer forma fica como alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

Os nossos teclados têm um [*layout* diferente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout).
É QWERTY, com as teclas especiais diferentes, e há uma variante portuguesa e uma variante brasileira.
Tem "[dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)" para todos os acentos e diacríticos, exceto o <kbd>ç</kbd> que tem a sua própria tecla.

Para escrever em português, podes mudar temporariamente o layout de teclado que usas, e escrever de memória (porque as teclas ficam diferentes dos símbolos que nelas têm escritos).
Chama-se a isto [*touch-typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing).
No tempo das máquinas de escrever, as pessoas eram treinadas para isto porque aumentava a sua velocidade de escrita e capacidade de trabalho (podiam ler e escrever ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo).

Também podes **remapear combinações de teclas**. Esta talvez seja a opção mais interessante.
Em Linux, podes [usar o utilitário `xkb`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04).
Em Windows há uma aplicação interessante para isso, chamada SharpKeys ([instruções](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/), via [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key/36922#36922)).

Ou podes criar o teu próprio *layout* de teclado, baseado no layout de teclado que usas agora, mas com dead keys e combinações especiais.
Eu [fiz isso](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key/723334#723334) para o meu teclado alemão. Troquei o <kbd>z</kbd> e o <kbd>y</kbd> <sup>[1]</sup>, tornei algumas teclas de acentos *dead keys* (nem todas eram), e adicionei atalhos adicionais como <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>->`ç`, <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>->`ã`, etc.

---

[1] é um teclado QWERTZ ao qual troquei fisicamente essas duas teclas

Answer (score 1):

Comummente em Portugal utilizamos um teclado com layout PT que tem teclas dedicadas para a introdução dos referidos caracteres.

Não tenho a certeza se isto funciona em Linux, porém no Windows sei é possível utilizar os "Alt Codes" para introduzir caracteres especiais.

Funciona pressionando a tecla <kbd>Alt</kbd> mais o correspondente código do carácter a introduzir utilizando o **NumPad**. Penso que isto não funcionará em teclados sem a parte numérica do lado direito como em versões compactas ou em muitos portáteis ou laptops.

Por exemplo pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> , <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> poderá introduzir o carácter C cedilhado "ç"

Podem encontrar-se [diversas listas completas de códigos](http://www.alt-codes.net/) de referência pesquisando na Internet.

Continua a não ser um método muito directo, mas memorizando os códigos mais frequentemente utilizados pode tornar-se ligeiramente rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Também uso o Linux com teclado EUA.

Embora já falaram sobre dead keys, creio ainda assim agregar algo com esta resposta.

**Funcionamento das Dead Keys**

Primeiramente sugiro 2 referências sobre o funcionamento de **Dead Keys**, uma sobre o conceito e funcionamento geral descrita no [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_keys), e como Dead Keys funcionam no [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97738) (desde o primeiro Windows 3.1) para o teclado Português BR, pelo menos. Se quiser poupar seu tempo, leia apenas a do Windows, esqueça a do Wikipedia.

O funcionamento no Windows é mais produtivo, pois você não precisa digitar espaço para obter o caractere original, apenas digite a tecla do acento agudo por exemplo, nada aparecerá, mas se em seguida você digitar algo que pode ser combinado com o acento agudo então ele será combinado, mas se você digitar algo que não pode ser combinado com o acento agudo (segundo as regras da língua configurada), dois caracteres aparecerão, o apóstrofo e o segundo caracter.

Daí é que vem o uso do espaço para obter o caractere original, já que o espaço não pode ser combinado com os diacríticos, porém, também ele não aparece como segundo caracter, já que não é um caractere, enfim, o espaço te permite obter o caractere original, limpinho, sem combiná-lo com ninguém. Este comportamento foi herdado das máquinas de escrever.

Infelizmente no Linux, nas configurações padrões (default), não é esse o comportamento. E você deve sempre usar o espaço para obter o caractere original. Horrível, baixa muito a produtividade na digitação. E eu também uso o Linux, e é algo que sempre brigo, uma batalha eterna, faço configurações manuais finas há anos, mas não fica, nunca, como o Windows. Até hoje não tive sucesso nessas configurações.

Uma alternativa, que eu não gosto muito, **mas pode ser útil para uso eventual do Português, talvez seja o seu caso**. É ter múltiplas configurações de teclado, e trocá-las quando for usar um ou outro.

A seguir um exemplo de configuração de 2 teclados no Linux Mint, ambos para teclado EUA:

**Configuração do teclado em Linux**

Em todos os *Linuxes* você encontrará alguma tela para configuração do teclado, nela você poderá adicionar layouts, e trocá-los, embora possa trocá-los também por atalhos do próprio teclado, ou por alguma ferramenta na bandeja do sistema (no Windows também).

Nesta tela também há um campo para você testar o teclado - Muito útil nas primeiras tentativas de configuração.

[image]

**Adição de novo layout**

[image]

**Escolhendo o layout**: US International keyboard layout with Dead Keys

[image]

**Ajuste fino das configurações de Dead Keys**

O legal do mundo Linux é que você pode mudar as coisas, e uma delas é configurar manualmente o comportamento das Dead Keys, detalhe por detalhe. Eu já segui alguns tutoriais, já fiz algumas, mas como já citei anteriormente, não tive sucesso esplêndido até agora, mas "dá pro gasto". Caso você consiga fazer o Linux se comportar exatamente como o Windows, compartilha com a gente !